# Invite created event (discord.js v12)

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I am trying to send an embed whenever a invite is created.

`Channel set file`

```
let config = require("../config.json");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
  name: "setinvite",
  description: "set invite channel log.",
  async execute(message, args) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission(`ADMINISTRATOR`)) {
      return message.channel.send(
        `:x: You do not have permission to use this command!`
      );
    } else {
      let channelx =
        message.mentions.channels.first() ||
        message.guild.channels.cache.find((c) => c.id === args[0]);
      if (!channelx)
        return message.channel.send(
          `:x: Please specify a channel to make it as the modlogs!`
        );

      message.channel.send(`${channelx} has been set!`);
    }
  },
};
```

`Index.js Modules` (PS: I took the most relevant ones.)

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const guildInvites = new Map();
const { channelx } = require("./commands/setinvite");
```

`Index.js file`

```
client.on("inviteCreate, message", async (invite) => {
  const setc = client.channels.cache.get(`${channelx}`);
  message.guild.fetchInvites().then((invites) => {
    let allInvites = invites.map((i) => ({
      name: "Invite",
      value: `**Inviter:** ${i.inviter}
    **Code:** https://discord.gg/${i.code}
    **Usages:** ${i.uses} of ${i.maxUses === 0 ? "∞" : i.maxUses}
    **Expires on:** ${
      i.maxAge
        ? new Date(i.createdTimestamp + i.maxAge * 1000).toLocaleString()
        : "never"
    }`,
      inline: true,
    }));

    setc.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().addFields(allInvites));
  });
});
```

I don't think the two events (`inviteCreate, message`) belong I did it because I received a **error**:

```
ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

Now, the channel set features works as intended but whenever the invite is created the embed doesn't send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't merge all events inside one function.

You only need to keep the [inviteCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-inviteCreate) event. Then, you have to find a way to get the guild without using the "message" variable. Instead you can use the "invite" parameter that is present inside the inviteCreate event.

```js
client.on("inviteCreate", async (invite) => {
  const setc = client.channels.cache.get(`${channelx}`);
  invite.guild.fetchInvites().then((invites) => {
    let allInvites = invites.map((i) => ({
      name: "Invite",
      value: `**Inviter:** ${i.inviter}
    **Code:** https://discord.gg/${i.code}
    **Usages:** ${i.uses} of ${i.maxUses === 0 ? "∞" : i.maxUses}
    **Expires on:** ${
      i.maxAge
        ? new Date(i.createdTimestamp + i.maxAge * 1000).toLocaleString()
        : "never"
    }`,
      inline: true,
    }));

    setc.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().addFields(allInvites));
  });
});
```

Comment: This sort seems like it fixed it but I am now receiving another error: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Comment: Your setc channel cannot be found. Make sure the channelx variable is a valid ID ^^

Comment: The `channelx` is defined in my other file and I imported it in the index.js file, perhaps I defined it incorrectly.